# how to bound android google maps to a specific span, so when the user pan he can't exceed that span?

Tags: android, maps

I want to bound google map in android around the UK,so the user can't pan the map to go outside uk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is definitely a way (or several ways) to do this for the maps web api (see links: http://econym.org.uk/gmap/range.htm and  http://econym.org.uk/gmap/epoly.htm). However, I don't know of a built-in way to do this on android, so it may take some hackery.

You will likely have to rewrite part of the mapview class... I'd try either overwriting the getMaxZoomLevel (as suggested in the first link - simpler but may not work) or trying to somehow intercept all the map movement requests and checking them to see if they fall outside of certain coordinates (harder/may not even be possible - probably have to do something like call getLongituteSpan every time the map moves and maybe try moving the map back if the span is outside your desired area?)